# Chrome Extension: How can I load a content.js file conditionally?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am not talking about ***executing*** a content script conditionally.

I know how to do that via `if (...) { chrome.scripting.executeScript(...) }`

I'm talking about not even having the content.js file available in the page's source code unless a condition is met.

In order for a Chrome Extension content script to run on a page, I need to declare it in the manifest like so:

```
"content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["https://allowed-host/*"],
      "js": [ "content.js" ]
    }
]
```

However, with the above, as soon as the user goes to `https://allowed-host/*` the `content.js` file becomes available on the Sources panel from what I can see (even if my extension chooses not to use it just yet).

I'm trying out https://extensionpay.com/ which is supposed to allow you to create subscription-based chrome extensions.

Inside **background.js** you can use the **ExtPay API** to see if the user has paid or not and execute code accordingly.

But my Chrome Extension relies on content scripts running on the page and manipulating the DOM and those script files themselves are available for anyone to view as soon as the relevant page loads, regardless of subscriptions etc.

Is there a way to prevent that ?

I understand I could set up my own server for this but I'm wondering if there is a no-backend-involved solution, only through the Chrome Extension API, where I could load a file on the page conditionally. Again, I'm not talking about executing the file conditionally, but loading it on the page, and making its source code available for anyone to view conditionally.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Surely those script files themselves are available for anyone to view as soon as **they download the extension**

Comment: I'm not sure you have access to the source code of a chrome extension you ***install via the Chrome Store directly***. But you do have access to all content scripts on the page's source code afterwards. But, for example, I don't think a user could gain access to the source code of a background.js script (?)

Comment: of course you have access to it. How else would the browser be able to run it?

Comment: Much like a user visiting a page doesn't have access to Chrome's internal code. For example, parts of the Chrome Extension API from the developer tools panel is not available for anyone to view or use but the browser runs it anyway.

Comment: I was hoping that the code of a chrome extension one builds could be "hidden" from the user in a similar fashion.

Comment: a user **running Chrome** **does** have access to Chrome's internal code. It's just hard to find.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244026/discussion-between-sprout-coder-and-user253751).

Comment: "It's just hard to find" That is what I was wondering. Whether a Chrome Extension's content scripts could be hidden and not be accessible easily via the Developer Tools. Apparently that is not possible.

Comment: Instead of `content_scripts` use chrome.scripting.registerContentScripts, see the documentation.

Comment: @wOxxOm the API is asking for an `id` for the script I want to register : `chrome.scripting.registerContentScripts([{ id, matches, js, css }])` but I don't know where to find it, because well.. the script has not been *registered* yet (!) :-/

Comment: Just invent it. For example, `foo`.

Comment: Yes! This works perfectly. When the user is not subscribed and I don't call `registerScripts()` the relevant scripts are not loaded and are therefore not accessible on Chrome's Developers Tools. Thanks, you can add it as an answer if you like :)